# React CSS modules import incopatible with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, css-modules

I want to use css modules in my react application. I installed 'typings-for-css-modules-loader' nuget package and configure in webpack.config.js like this

```
test: /\.css$/,
use: [
    'style-loader',
    '@teamsupercell/typings-for-css-modules-loader',
    {
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
            modules: true,
        }
    }
]
```

file styles.css.d.ts is generated and looks like this:

```
export interface IStylesCss {
  x: string;
}

export const locals: IStylesCss;
export default locals;
```

i am using awesome-typescript-loader which is configured in webpack.config.js as follows:

```
{
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    use:
    {
        loader: "awesome-typescript-loader"
    }
},
```

Here is a problem description:

If i use `import * as styles from './styles.css';` + `className={styles.x}` not working due to compilation error 'Property 'x' does not exist on type ...'

`className={styles.default.x}` do not work either because default is undefined.

default import `import styles from './styles.css';` + `className={styles.x}` not working, again, a default is undefined.

`import * as styles from './styles.css';` + `className={(styles as any).x}` **is working but** i loose strong typing and it doesnt look correct solution to me.

Comment: Same problem, any updates on it ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting allowSyntheticDefaultImports and esModuleInterop to true in tsconfig.json asi hotfix worked for me. Waiting for fix.